# YouTubeAndroidPlayer on Android crashes on play()

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm trying to embed a YouTubePlayerView in my Android application.
I'm using YouTubePlayerAPI v1.2.1 on Android API 17.

It comes with a warning before crashing which probably has something to do with it.

The crash happens when player.play() is called. I do get a still however before I push play.

Any ideas?

```
02-20 15:52:07.924    6647-6867/? W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ (unknown)   setKeepScreenOn should be through player Surface, not SurfaceHolder
02-20 15:52:07.934    6647-6867/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d57930)
02-20 15:52:07.944    6647-6867/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: YouTubePlayer.MediaPlayerThread
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
        at atz.getSurfaceContext(SourceFile)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDisplay(MediaPlayer.java:682)
        at gos.a(SourceFile:174)
        at goy.a(SourceFile:410)
        at goy.a(SourceFile:40)
        at gpd.handleMessage(SourceFile:792)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```